# Why when playing images in a pictureBox1 using a timer the playing is getting very slow?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

At the first time when I click the button it's showing the images in the `pictureBox1` one by one fast. But then after some images it's getting very slow.
It's showing the images one by one very slow like in slow motion mode.

This is the button click event code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _files = new List<FileInfo>(); 
    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value = 0;
    _indx = 0;
    _files.AddRange(_fi);
    _files = _files.OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime).ToList();
    button5.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    button6.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    button7.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    timer3.Start();
    button6.Enabled = true;
    button6.Text = "Pause";
    button7.Enabled = true;    
}
```

The variable `_indx` is global `int`.

Then the timer3 tick event:

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum = _files.Count;
        myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
        Image iOLd = this.pictureBox1.Image;
        Image img = Image.FromFile(_files[_indx].FullName);
        myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value = _indx;
        label22.Text = _files[_indx].Name;
        this.pictureBox1.Image = img;
        if (iOLd != null)
            iOLd.Dispose();

        _indx++;
        if (_indx >= _files.Count)
        {
            _indx = 0;
        }

        timer3.Interval = 40;
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Sometimes when I click the button once the timer start it's showing the images in the `pictureBox1` very slow. Sometimes it's showing them fast like interval 40 and then in some point it's getting slow. I can't figure out why it's getting slow.

Comment: Looking at your timer interval you are firing timer's tick event every 40 milliseconds. You may be getting a slowdown because you are sending one too many request per second. In timer's tick event you are constructing image object from file which can get slow as your images resides on disk.

Comment: Removed the try/catch i also moved the trackbar1 maximum and minimum lines to the button click event and also the timer3 interval = 40 moved it to the button click event. But still getting the problem.

Comment: @Hakunamatata i tried to change now the interval of timer3 to 500 and it seems that now it keep the same speed. But 500 is very slow.

Comment: Not knowing wither the file sizes (do they vary?) not your hardware it is hard to know for sure. But with juman eyesight being limited to less 16fps, the interval should be > 60 anyway or else the frames will only be a blur.. If you actually want to create an animation you should a) preload all images, if size allows, into an `ImageList` and b) choose a fast pixelformat, i.e. [Format32bppPArgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Declare what you can outside of the timer. Instantiating variables every tick will cause some throttle.. actually why even store those variables in memory? get rid of iOld and img if you can...

Declared and instantiated outside of function:

```
    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum = _files.Count;
    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
```

Timer Tick:

```
try {
        this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(_files[_indx].FullName);
        timer3.Interval = 40;
        _indx++;
}
```